# Issue retrieving data from firebase database ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication

At the moment I have an app that is using Firebase database to store the users:
Name
School
Subject
Within three separate textfields.

Right now I've managed to allow the user to enter his details within these three text fields and hit a button labeled update, which then sends the data to my firebase console.

This means that the user can enter their details, hit update and see them while they are logged in. however as soon as they logout and login again the textfields are blank, despite the fact that firebase has the info stored on its server.

I've been playing around all day trying to get it to work but to no avail.

Here we have the firebase reference and auth:

```
    self.rootRef = [[FIRDatabase database] reference];  
    self.user = [FIRAuth auth].currentUser;
```

And the update button code that sends the users info to the firebase database:

```
- (IBAction)didTapEditProfile:(id)sender {  

if (![_textFieldOne.text  isEqual: @""]) {  

    NSString *item = _textFieldOne.text;  

    [[[[_rootRef child:@"users"] child:_user.uid] child:@"Name"] setValue:item];  
}  

if (![_textFieldTwo.text  isEqual: @""]) {  

    NSString *itemTwo = _textFieldTwo.text;  

    [[[[_rootRef child:@"users"] child:_user.uid] child:@"School"] setValue:itemTwo];  

}  

if (![_textFieldThree.text  isEqual: @""]) {  

    NSString *itemThree = _textFieldThree.text;  

    [[[[_rootRef child:@"users"] child:_user.uid] child:@"Subject"] setValue:itemThree];  

}  

}
```

The problem i'm having is with retrieving the data within the code below which is situated in the viewDidAppear:

```
    [[_rootRef child:@"users"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {  

    NSDictionary *usersDict = snapshot.value;  

    NSLog(@"%@",usersDict);  

   [usersDict objectForKey:_user.uid];  

   //I've tried numerous solutions here to get the text fields to display the info from the database   
    mainly: 
 NSString *field;
 field = _textFieldOne.text;
 field = [userDict objectForKey @"Name"];

 The code i'm attempting to translate from looks like this:    
 field(userDict?.objectForKey("Name") as? String)

}];
```

Any ideas?

Comment: you need to assign the field to the textfield text so that the textfield updates. Currently you only store it in a object

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I managed to get everything sorted as follows:

```
-(void)configure:(NSString *)field {

    _textFieldOne.text = field;

}
```

and then within the code I was having the problem:

```
    [[_rootRef child:@"users"] observeEventType:FIRDataEventTypeValue withBlock:^(FIRDataSnapshot * _Nonnull snapshot) {  

    NSDictionary *usersDict = snapshot.value;  

    NSLog(@"%@",usersDict);  

    [usersDict objectForKey:_user.uid];  

    [self configure:[userDict objectForKey:@"Name"]];


}];
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3):

Hey Joshua I have implemented the firebase and successfully retrieve the data from the firebase but the problem is i have implemented that in swift... here is my actual code if this helps you......

```
**rootRef.queryOrderedByChild("search what you want like specific name etc etc").observeEventType(.ChildAdded, withBlock: { snapshot in
            if snapshot.value is NSNull {
                print("the chat model is null")
                SVProgressHUD.dismiss()
                SVProgressHUD.showErrorWithStatus("No messages")
            }
            else {
                print(snapshot) }**
```

Or if you want to fetch the whole database JSON here is the query

```
**rootref.observeEventType(.ChildAdded) { (snapshot: FDataSnapshot!) in
    // 3
    let id = snapshot.value["senderId"] as! String
    let text = snapshot.value["text"] as! String

    // 4
    self.addMessage(id, text: text)

    // 5
    self.finishReceivingMessage()
  }**
```

Here is a nice tutorial on this 
**https://www.raywenderlich.com/122148/firebase-tutorial-real-time-chat**

If you want this to convert in objective-c then of course I will help you

Comment: Thanks shafi, the reason i'm currently stuck is because i'm already translating from swift. I've highlighted what the swift code looks like in my description at the bottom